# would you prohibit me from this container design and use?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, templates, containers

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//I want such a container that holds an array and don't want to expose array directly

template <size_t T>
class Container{
    public:
        Container(int in[]);
        int getValue(const unsigned int pos);
        //void setValue(const unsigned int pos,const int value);
        unsigned int getSize();
        /*...
        ...
        ...*/

        unsigned int theSize;
        int theArray[T];
};

template <size_t T>
Container<T>::Container(int in[]){
    theSize=T;
    for (unsigned int i=0;i<T;i++)
        theArray[i]=in[i];
}
template <size_t T>
int Container<T>::getValue(const unsigned int pos){return theArray[pos];}
template <size_t T>
unsigned int Container<T>::getSize(){
    return theSize;
}
//then I want to pass objects of this type around by address, but then to use that address //I have to do such design as follows, now would you prohibit me from doing this?

void someFunc(void * in){
    Container<1> * ptr=reinterpret_cast<Container<1> *>(in);
    unsigned int times=ptr->getSize();
    for (unsigned int i=0;i<times;i++)
        cout <<ptr->getValue(i)<<' ';
    cout <<'\n';

}

int main(int argc,char ** argv){

    int araye[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    Container<10> obj(araye);

    someFunc(&obj);

    cin.get();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I would prohibit you from implementing this container.  You are reinventing the wheel, and as far as I can tell there's no reason to.

Use a `std::array` instead.  Even if you can't use C++11 (where `array` was introduced), you should use something already designed, built and tested like `std::vector`.

Comment: well what I meant was if I'm doing something technically wrong!

Comment: @Pooria:  Fair enough, but writing this thing is wrong from word Go.  Wrong is wrong, be it for technical or design issues.  Please reconsider writing this at all.

Comment: @Pooria If you're looking for somebody to tell you if there are problems with your code, you want to go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I have strange thoughts you know ;)